# Aiogram 2.25.1 Ошибка AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'copy_message'. Did you mean: 'send_message'?

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Для проект друг попросил доработать код телеграмм бота aiogram, у него идеально все работает. У меня же выдаёт данную ошибку. Попросил его сгенерировать requirements.txt. Вот его requirements.txt:

```
aiofiles==23.2.1
aiogram==2.25.1
aiohttp==3.8.5
aiosignal==1.3.1
annotated-types==0.5.0
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrs==23.1.0
Babel==2.9.1
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.3.0
coloredlogs==15.0.1
executor==23.2
fasteners==0.19
frozenlist==1.4.0
humanfriendly==10.0
idna==3.4
magic-filter==1.0.12
multidict==6.0.4
mysql-connector-python==8.1.0
property-manager==3.0
protobuf==4.21.12
pydantic==2.3.0
pydantic_core==2.6.3
pyreadline3==3.4.1
pytz==2023.3.post1
six==1.16.0
typing_extensions==4.7.1
verboselogs==1.7
yarl==1.9.2
```

Ошибка в том что в Bot не находит метод copy_message. У друга все находит, вопрос как исправить, чтобы метод copy_message работал. Вот код main.py

```
# main.py
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import ParseMode, Message
from aiogram.utils import executor

import aiogram.types.message
import datetime

from Data.base import add_user
from func.functions import navigator_buttons
from func.functions import callbeck_bron_data
from func.functions import button_bron_menu
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
    
token = 'Какой-то токен'

button_search = KeyboardButton('Поиск свободных полей ')
button_bron = KeyboardButton('Бронировать поля ')

inline_btn_next = InlineKeyboardButton("▶️", callback_data='next_3')
inline_btn_back = InlineKeyboardButton("◀️", callback_data='back_10')
inline_btn_bron = InlineKeyboardButton('Забронировать поля ', callback_data='bron_2')
inline_count = InlineKeyboardButton("1/9", callback_data='1.9')


inline_bron_date = InlineKeyboardButton(f"21-11", callback_data='21-11')
inline_bron_date_back = InlineKeyboardButton('<-', callback_data='date_back')
inline_bron_date_next = InlineKeyboardButton('->', callback_data='date_next')

inline_bron_btn = InlineKeyboardButton("Забронироваить", callback_data='bron')


inline_pay_1h_btn = InlineKeyboardButton('Оплатить ', url='https://s.binance.com/lhSHP6w8')
cheek_pay_btn = InlineKeyboardButton('Проверить', callback_data='cheek')


inline_back_menu = InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='menu')

button_navigator = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
button_navigator.add(inline_btn_back, inline_btn_next)
button_navigator.row(inline_btn_bron)
button_navigator.row(inline_count)



inline_pay_btn = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
inline_pay_btn.add(inline_pay_1h_btn,cheek_pay_btn,inline_back_menu)



kb_menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
kb_menu.add(button_search, button_bron)

bot = Bot(token=token, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot)




@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def message_handler(message: Message):
    
    add_user(chat_id=message.from_user.id, name=message.from_user.full_name)

    text = "Добро пожаловать в PLSportBot\nЯ помогу тебе в поиске и бронирование футбольных полей."

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text, reply_markup=kb_menu)


@dp.message_handler()
async def handler_menu(message: Message):
    chat_id = message.from_user.id

    if message.text == "Поиск свободных полей ":
        await bot.copy_message(chat_id=chat_id, from_chat_id=-1001522689909, message_id=2, reply_markup=button_navigator)

@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def agree_ref_start(query: types.callback_query):
    data_str = query.data
    if  data_str.find("next") != -1 or data_str.find("back") != -1:
        message_id = query.data
        message_id = message_id.split('_')[1]
        btn = navigator_buttons(messega_id=message_id)
        
        
        await bot.delete_message(chat_id=query.message.chat.id, message_id=query.message.message_id)
        # await bot.send_message(chat_id=query.message.chat.id, text=message_id)
        await bot.copy_message(chat_id=query.message.chat.id, from_chat_id=-1001522689909, message_id=message_id, reply_markup=btn)


    if  data_str.find("bron") != -1 :
        bron_id = query.data
        bron_id = bron_id.split('_')[1]

        button_brom_menu1 = button_bron_menu(data_str)

        await bot.send_message(chat_id=query.message.chat.id, text=f"Вы хотите забронироваить поля под id:{bron_id}\n\nПожалуйста выберите время:",reply_markup=button_brom_menu1)

    elif data_str == "cheek":
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=query.message.chat.id, text=f"id заявки: #{query.message.chat.id}\n\nВаш заявка отправлена, пожалуйста подождите...")

    elif data_str.find('h') != -1:

        text = callbeck_bron_data(data_str)

        await bot.send_message(chat_id=query.message.chat.id, text=text,reply_markup=inline_pay_btn)

    elif data_str == 'menu':
         await bot.delete_message(chat_id=query.message.chat.id, message_id=query.message.message_id)
         await bot.delete_message(chat_id=query.message.chat.id, message_id=query.message.message_id-1)
        
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(
        dispatcher=dp,
        skip_updates=True
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def handler_menu(message: Message, bot: Bot): # допишите bot: Bot
    chat_id = message.from_user.id

    if message.text == "Поиск свободных полей ":
        await bot.copy_message(chat_id=chat_id, from_chat_id=-1001522689909, message_id=2, reply_markup=button_navigator)
```